# mysql.data conflict something in my entity framework project

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ado.net, ef-model-first, mysql.data

I'm using MySQL database in my Ado.Net project. So I am using entity framework model first. It is good but when i want to add "mysql.data" (which i get from mysql web site named mysql data connector) to the Referances, it gives me an error like this: "object reference not set to an instance of an object". When i remove mysql.data from Referances, it works good. I think, it may cause mysq.data. I want to use mysql.data for searching queries. Because i don't know to code searching queries entity framework in my mysql ado.net project.
Could you help me, how do I solve the problem? I want to use both mysql.data and entity framework model first in my project.
Sincerely yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I solved the problem. I provided "mysql.data.entity.dll" from MySQL web site, I added to referances and now everything is good.